# Handling array inside array JSON in table

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a JSON Response as follows JSON :

```
var res =   
     {
      "response": {
        "data": {
          "profilesearchsnippet": [
            [
              {
                "profileInfo": {
                  "firstname": "Sundar",
                  "lastname": "v",
                  "gender": "male",
                  "country": "Afghanistan",
                  "state": "Badakhshan",
                  "city": "Eshkashem",
                  "pincode": "",
                  "plancode": "T001",
                  "userid": 13
                },
                "roleInfo": {
                  "defaultphotoid": 94
                }
              }
            ],
            [
              {
                "profileInfo": {
                  "firstname": "ghg",
                  "lastname": "vbhvh",
                  "gender": "male",
                  "state": "Badakhshan",
                  "city": "Eshkashem",
                  "pincode": "454",
                  "plancode": "T001",
                  "userid": 22
                },
                "roleInfo": {
                  "defaultphotoid": 171
                }
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to fetch all firstname , country state city in a table.I tried assigning profilesearchsnippet value to variable var SearchData and try fetching firstname by using profileinfo,since its object. I am missing something somewhere need assistance.

HTML:

```
 <tr ng-repeat= "item in searchData">
        <td>{{item.profileInfo.firstname}}</td>
        <td> {{item.profileInfo.country}}</td>
      </tr>
```

JS:

```
var searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet[0];
```

Comment: Have you assigned searchData to something like controller or scope ?

Comment: searchData is not the iterable you are looking for, you defined it as `var searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet[0];` this is just one of the search results. Try without the `[0]`.

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/XQismiIYFLTDy2y7sdQg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Js get like this:-

```
var searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet[0];;
```

In Html:-

```
 <div ng-repeat= "item in searchData">
 <tr ng-repeat= "itm in item">
        <td>{{itm.profileInfo.firstname}}</td>
        <td> {{itm.profileInfo.country}}</td>
      </tr>
 <div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr ng-repeat= "item in searchData">
    <td>{{item[0].profileInfo.firstname}}</td>
    <td> {{item[0].profileInfo.country}}</td>
  </tr>
```

The data that you want to access is inside another array with single value so access it with index.

Answer (score 1):

You will get only one using:

```
var searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet[0];
```

Try this:

```
var searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet;
```

and in `template`:

```
<tr ng-repeat= "item in searchData">
    <td>{{item[0].profileInfo.firstname}}</td>
    <td> {{item[0].profileInfo.country}}</td>
  </tr>
```

**UPDATED:**

```
item[0].profileInfo
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is your requirement and you dint have country 
 field for GHG so it wont show up in output instead that i added a static msg

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat= "item in searchData">
        <p>{{item[0].profileInfo.firstname}}</p>
         <p>{{item[0].profileInfo.country ||"no country data available "}}</p>
        
      </div>
  </body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = {
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "profilesearchsnippet": [
        [
          {
            "profileInfo": {
              "firstname": "Sundar",
              "lastname": "v",
              "gender": "male",
              "country": "Afghanistan",
              "state": "Badakhshan",
              "city": "Eshkashem",
              "pincode": "",
              "plancode": "T001",
              "userid": 13
            },
            "roleInfo": {
              "defaultphotoid": 94
            }
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "profileInfo": {
              "firstname": "ghg",
              "lastname": "vbhvh",
              "gender": "male",
              "state": "Badakhshan",
              "city": "Eshkashem",
              "pincode": "454",
              "plancode": "T001",
              "userid": 22
            },
            "roleInfo": {
              "defaultphotoid": 171
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
};
$scope.searchData = $scope.name.response.data.profilesearchsnippet;

});

</script>
</html>
```